# Why is Carrie allowed to just go about freely?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

In *Homeland* S08E11, Carrie is charged with many things, including accessory to murder of the President and providing material support to a terrorist organization.

Yet afterwards she is just allowed to go about freely, including to Pennsylvania to meet up with Andrei Kuznetsov and later also the Russian agent Charlotte to Skype with Yevgeny Gromov. (And all this apparently with no one monitoring her.)

(Edit: In S08E12, she even leaves the US to visit Saul's sister in the occupied territories of the West Bank.)

Is there any plausible legal reason for this?

Comment: In ep12 she probably escapes the country under a false name, notice her bag full of different passports.

Answer (score 3):

Saul [posted bail/put up bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail#Bail_bond) for Carrie. This doesn't quite explain why in the first place bail wasn't denied, but it does explain why she isn't held in jail or has an ankle monitor or anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]